# intel parallel studio 2011 on visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intel, icc

Do you know where I can fin good tutorials for beginners about intel parallel studio 2011 on visual studio 2010?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation contains [tutorials](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/studio/en-us/2011/start/index.htm) that I found to be good.